# Install Hokuyo Node on hydro

Tags: ros, urg-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,

I am trying to run hokuyo urg-04lx-ug01.
But it seems missing from the package hydro.
The command

```
rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node
```

is not run successfully.
return error

```
Error: stack/package hokuyo_node not found
```

install the package

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-laser-drivers
```

puts the additional package under fuerte folder, not able to be called in hydro.

I notice there's another package urg_node, but I can't find the install instruction.

How to install it under hydro?

regards
Ray

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189725/install-hokuyo-node-on-hydro/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Replace the ros **-fuerte-** laser-drivers with **-hydro-**.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-laser-drivers
```

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3